# React-router: Create routes from higher-order-component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'd like to specify some special properties for my routes, namely: asyncLoad= true/false, pregenerate static html: true/false and some other.

For this, I'd like to create own createRoutes script, which would look very simmilar to classical react-router definition, but would loop through routes and return the classical react-router createRoutes file. Do you have any ideas/resources how to do that? Thank you.

Comment: Are you attempting to do this in v2/3 or v4? I am not sure I understand the question fully. Maybe a sample of how you expect to use it or expected output.

Comment: v3. Sample code: let oRoutesToCount = [
  { path: 'about', component: './home/AboutUs.react.js', async: true},
  { path: 'another-path', component: './home/AboutUs.react.js', async: true},
]; - then i'll loop over them and make router config from them, but this way it will be quicker to make all async loading definitions

Comment: Have you looked into v4 at all, I know there is an addon that uses a json route setup similar to this. It may be simpler to extend it than to try and roll your own from scratch. https://react-router.now.sh/route-config